# How many positive integers $n$ are there such that $2n$ and $2n^2+1$ are both perfect squares?

Tags: number-theory, square-numbers

How many positive integers $n$ are there such that $2n$ and $2n^2+1$ are both perfect squares?
$n=2$ is the only solution I can find. Are there others?

Comment: https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-solve-x-2-8y-2-1-over-the-positive-integers

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Although, since $2n$ must be a square, here the probem is equivalent to the Diophantine equation $h^2-8k^4=1$, i.e. you would want to find the solution to $h^2-8t^2=1$ such that $t$ is a square. That doesn't seem immediate to me.

Comment: To explain the previous comment: If $2n=m^2$, then $m$ must be even, so $m^2$ must be a multiple of $4$, so $n$ must be even. Replacing $n=2t$ produces the equivalent requirement that $4t$ and $8t^2+1$ are perfect squares. Since $4$ is a perfect square, the first requirement is equivalent to $t$ being a perfect square. Replacing $t=k^2$ produces the requirement that $8k^4+1$ is a perfect square; call it $h^2$. So we have $h^2-8k^4=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Not a perfect solution... but maybe can be a hint.

$2n$ is perfect square, so let $n=2k^2$.

Therefore, $8k^4+1$ is also a perfect square.

let $8k^4+1=l^2$.

Then, $l^2-8k^4=1.$

let $k^2=m$, which leads to:

$l^2-8m^2=1.$

This is a Pell equation. solving this, we get:

$(l, m)=(3, 1), (17, 6), ..., \left( \dfrac{(3+\sqrt8)^{\alpha}+(3-\sqrt{8})^{\alpha}}{2}, \dfrac {(3+\sqrt{8})^{\alpha}-(3-\sqrt{8})^{\alpha}} {2\sqrt{8}} \right), ...$ .

So, the number of $n$ will be the number of the perfect square of $\dfrac{(3+\sqrt8)^{\alpha}-(3-\sqrt8)^{\alpha}}{2\sqrt8}$. This can be also written:

$ (3+\sqrt{8})^{\alpha-1} + (3+\sqrt{8})^{\alpha-2}(3-\sqrt{8})+\cdots+(3+\sqrt{8})(3-\sqrt{8})^{\alpha-2}+(3-\sqrt{8})^{\alpha-1} $.

Use that $(3+\sqrt{8})(3-\sqrt{8})=1.$